# convert the image value array into x/y coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to find the x/y coordinate of the edge after using canny edge detection with openCV

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('star.png',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image] before

[image] after turning it into grey scale and canny's edge detection

the data values is stored in variable "edges", is there a way to take the value of the actual edge and turn it into x,y coord

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the edge coordinates by using numpy library:

```
xAxis, yAxis = np.nonzero(edges)
```

In here **xAxis** and **yAxis** include all the x and y axis respectively belong to the edge which **canny** detected. You can also simply calculate the average of these coordinates which mean the center of detected edge coordinates:

```
centerX = int(np.mean(xAxis))
centerY = int(np.mean(yAxis))
```

Here is the whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.core.defchararray import center
img = cv.imread('/home/yns/Downloads/st.jpg',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)

xAxis, yAxis = np.nonzero(edges)

centerX = int(np.mean(xAxis))
centerY = int(np.mean(yAxis))


cv.circle(img,(centerX,centerY),5,(0,255,255),3)


plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```